# Rendering link on facebook did not get the correct metas

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

When I past the link on facebook "www.testurl.com/profile" I did not get the correct metas. I am using react helmet component and I tried to add {og:title and og:decription} it did not work. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should render website at server because Facebook Bots isn't render your React app. They are just see your empty application so you must render your app and sent string when a social media bot visited your website. We are doing it with some nginx configs and prerender package. You can try.

Default prerender use 4201 port

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yourservername.com;

    root /var/www/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201/render?url=https://www.yourwebsite.com$request_uri;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. This is what I just did. but my current problem is in server.js file app.get('/profile', function(){}); The problem is that the app listening on port e.g 3000 -> app.listen(3000);
so when access url through (www.testutl.com:3000/profile) it worked. but what I need to let it works without adding :3000 in the url!

Comment: You can do this with Nginx configurations, please wait ı will write settings for you.

Comment: Okay, I am waiting
Thanks

Comment: You should add this code to your Nginx configuration

Comment: Default at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Comment: Is there a doc to how add Nginx conf. using npm? I do not really know from where I should start!
this is the first time I am using this conf.

Comment: I am using apche not nginx. is there a way to do the cong through apache?

Comment: I do not know you must search about forwarding port to port with match useragent using regex